# Send email from php

Tags: php

I am designing a PHP page to send an email. An error is occurring. Please check my code carefully and let me know the error in my code.

This is the output which is generated when i run my program:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
```

so pls help me to set smtp configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `$header` to `$headers`, you've got `$headers  = "From: $from\r\n";` and using `$header`

mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);

so whole code would look like

```
<?php 
    //change this to your email. 
    $to = "kuntal.pushpendra@gmail.com"; 
    $from = "puskun.pericent@gmail.com"; 
    $subject = "Hello! This is HTML email"; 
    $message = "hello";
    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n"; 
    mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers); 

    echo "Message has been sent....!"; 
?>
```

Comment: this error is ocuured Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\MusicApplication\mail.php on line 28

Comment: it's because you have to set up mailserver first, before sending actual email :)

Comment: sir, please tell me how can i setup my mail server..? can i send mail using localhost ?

Comment: you should have SMTP server first.

Comment: means i cant send mail using my localhost..?

Comment: I'm afraid it will be horror in Windows

Answer (score 3):

Your mail() function is using $header instead of the variable $headers.

Try `mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers);` instead.

Comment: what should i do to handle this error..?    Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\MusicApplication\mail.php on line 32

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a mail server (an SMTP one), in order to enable your server to send email.
Another way to do that, is to use someone else's mail server, like your' company's, or even the Gmail ones.

A good library to abstract the server SMTP connection is [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). It's a robust and well known mailer library, used in projects like symfony.

Comment: sir do you know how can we setup our mail server(smtp) for php ?

Comment: Depend on what Os is on your server. I'm sure you can find the answer on SO.